# How to assign whole table with column and add active flag in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables - cards and colors.

```
CREATE TABLE cards(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  text text NOT NULL CHECK (text <> ''),
  colors integer[] DEFAULT array[]::integer[]
);
CREATE TABLE colors(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  color text NOT NULL
);
```

Colors table contains all available colors. 
Colors column, in cards table, contain ids of colors, related to particular card.

I need select all cards, where each card should contain array with all available colors and each color should have `active` property, which tells has card this color or not
For example if cards and colors tables have these entries:

```
cards:

 id |  text  | colors 
----+--------+--------
 1  | card 1 | {1,2}
 2  | card 2 | {}

colors:
 id | color 
----+-------
  1 | red
  2 | green
  3 | blue
```

Needed result should be:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  text: 'card 1',
  colors: [{
    id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    active: true,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    color: 'green',
    active: true,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    color: 'blue',
    active: false,
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'card 2',
  colors: [{
    id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    active: false,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    color: 'green',
    active: false,
  }, {
    id: 3,
    color: 'blue',
    active: false,
  }]
}]
```

To assign all available colors with `colors` column in cards table, I used this query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.text, json_agg(cl) AS colors FROM cards AS c
LEFT JOIN colors AS cl ON (cl.id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY c.id
```

But how I can add `active` flag to each color?
I tried to use `select` inside of join:

```
SELECT c.id, c.text, json_agg(cl) AS colors FROM cards AS c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT cl.id, cl.color, cl.id = ANY(c.colors) AS active
  FROM colors AS cl
) AS cl ON (cl.id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY c.id
```

But it returns an error - `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "c"`
As I understand, I can't have access to `c` reference in query inside of join.
So, how to make this code correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested aggregation of `json` objects that you build from the data in the tables. Just keep on applying simple logic and you'll get there:

```
SELECT json_agg(jsons)
FROM (
    SELECT json_build_object(
             'id', cards.id, 
             'text', cards.text,
             'colors', json_agg(json_build_object(
                                  'id', colors.id,
                                  'color', colors.color,
                                  'active', colors.id = ANY (cards.colors)
                                                 )
                               )
                            ) jsons
    FROM cards
    CROSS JOIN colors
    GROUP BY cards.id
    ORDER BY cards.id) sub;
```

The trick here is the `CROSS JOIN` which yields:

```
id |   text   | colors  | id | color
---+----------+---------+----+--------
 1 | 'card 1' | '{1,2}' |  1 | 'red'
 1 | 'card 1' | '{1,2}' |  2 | 'green'
 1 | 'card 1' | '{1,2}' |  3 | 'blue'
 2 | 'card 2' | '{}'    |  1 | 'red'
 2 | 'card 2' | '{}'    |  2 | 'green'
 2 | 'card 2' | '{}'    |  3 | 'blue'
```

The `active` column is then simply constructed from `colors.id = ANY (cards.colors)`. From then on it is `json_build_object()` and `json_agg()` until you are done. Since you can't nest two aggregate functions you need a sub-query.